# TServerSocket and TClientSocket

Tags: delphi

I use this code to reveive data :
But It's not work.Can you Help me ?

```
procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  i:integer;
  sRec : string;
begin
  for i := 0 to ServerSocket1.Socket.ActiveConnections-1 do
  begin
    with ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[i] do
    begin
      sRec:=ReceiveText;
      if sRec <> '' then
      begin
        if RemoteAddress='192.168.0.1' then
        begin
          if ReceiveText='1' then
            Btn1.Color:=clNavy;
          ADOQuery1.Active:=True;
        end;
        if RemoteAddress='192.168.0.1' then
        begin
          if ReceiveText='2' then
            Btn1.Color:=clRed;
          Pnl1.Visible:=True;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What is the error? What is sending the data?

Comment: Please, elaborate on what really means _it's not work_

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to read from EVERY client connection in the TServerSocket.Socket.Connections list whenever ANY client sends data. You should be using the TCustomWinSocket parameter that the event provides instead.  It tells you the exact client that is sending data.

You also have some other logic errors in your code as well.

Try this instead:

```
procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  sRec : string;
begin
  sRec := Socket.ReceiveText;
  if sRec <> '' then
  begin
    if Socket.RemoteAddress = '192.168.0.1' then
    begin
      if sRec = '1' then Btn1.Color := clNavy;
      ADOQuery1.Active := True;
      if sRec = '2' then Btn1.Color := clRed;
      Pnl1.Visible := True;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Or maybe you meant something more like this?

```
procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  sRec : string;
begin
  sRec := Socket.ReceiveText;
  if sRec <> '' then
  begin
    if Socket.RemoteAddress = '192.168.0.1' then
    begin
      if sRec = '1' then begin
        Btn1.Color := clNavy;
        ADOQuery1.Active := True;
      end
      else if sRec = '2' then begin
        Btn1.Color := clRed;
        Pnl1.Visible := True;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It works perfect.Thank You. Do you know can i send data from TServerSocket to TClientSocket ???and if i can... how ?

Comment: Of course you can.  If you want to send data from inside one of the server's event handlers, then simply use the same `TCustomWinSocket` object that the event provides.  Otherwise, you have to locate the desired client in the server's `Connections[]` list and then send to that socket.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that if the server is running in non-blocking mode, and you try to send more data than a socket can handle at a given moment, the send will fail with an WSAEWOULDBLOCK error code, then you have to cache whatever pending data you have remaining and wait until the server's OnClientWrite event is fired before you can send more data to that same socket again.

Comment: Search the forum archives at http://groups.google.com and http://forums.embarcadero.com, examples have been posted many times before.

Answer (score -1):

Replace ServerSocket1.Socket with Socket param and test again. Of couse to remove the for loop

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand you.What you want to say with Socket Param.